# Check if a string contains the keywords of a file c#

Tags: c#, string, contains, keyword

I'm trying to check if a string contains a keyword present in a text file but nothing was done

If you need more information ask me

For exemple i have a keywords.txt like this :

```
example1
example2
example3
```

and i want to see if one of these keyword are in a json string like this :

```
{ 
     "title":"new doc 4",
     "rotate":0,
     "sort_key":"new doc 4",
     "tag_ids":"",
     "doc_id":"ee4DM4Ly7CFBM3JFWAW60TUX",
     "co_token":"",
     "p":"XQXLDEQyA2hf6BBfyXhSaUHL",
     "t":"1474932063",
     "c":"2",
     "updated":"1474932063"
}
```

You can see what i have try below
So I'm hoping you can help me solve this problem thanks

```
if (json.Contains(File.ReadAllText(@"keywords.txt")))
{
    //My if logic
}
else
{
    //My else logic
}
```

Comment: In my keywords file I have one word per line for example : 
```example1
example2```
And I want to see if in my string json which for example is: 
```"title":"new doc 5",
            "rotate":0,
            "sort_key":"new doc 5",
            "tag_ids":"",
            "doc_id":"Xy67QdRhTR9XS159WLyCCTbK",
            "co_token":"",
            "p":"XadS23UUQbQRQt9gLPWDWTAQ",
            "t":"1474932060",
            "c":"1",
            "updated":"1474932061"```
And I want to see if in this string there's one of the words in my keyword file...

Comment: I've edited my main message with more details

Comment: hi @FanTaZy yf, I think you need to be looking for specific keyword in your json. For example, if your keywords contain `example` and your json string contains `example1` it will give you a false positive, you can refer to my solution below !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want check any word in file contains in string then, first you need to [store all lines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) from file into an Array, then you need to string contains any of string from array or not.

[Enumerable.Any method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
>   condition.

To do that try below,

```
var examples = File.ReadAllLines(@"keywords.txt");

if(examples.Any(x => json.Contains(x))
{
  //Your business logic
}
else
{
  //Your business logic
}
```

---

If you want to check exact match then you can try with RegEx `IsMatch()` function

like,

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
var examples = File.ReadAllLines(@"keywords.txt");

//If you want to ignore case then, pass third parameter to IsMatch() "RegexOptions.IgnoreCase"
if(examples.Any(x => Regex.IsMatch(json, $@"\b{x}\b"))   
{
  // here "\b" stands for boundary
  //Your business logic
}
else
{
  //Your business logic
}
```

Comment: This approach will give incorrect result if the keywords contain "keyword" and json contains "keyword5". What are your thoughts ?
Which is handled in the answer below :)

Comment: @Clint, good catch and thanks for helping me to improve my answer. Have a look at updated answer.

Comment: @Prasasd, you're welcome, I am yet to test the above method in `Regex` ill confirm once I do :)

Answer (score 1):

The below approach will help eliminate the ***false positives***, it checks if the ***Specific*** keyword is present in the JSON string and only then process further

> Just doing `String.contains` might swallow these false positives and
>   come up as *true*

**Input File KeyWords**

```
keyword  //This will return as false
keyword1 //This will return true
```

**Input File Json**

```
{ 
   "title":"new doc 4",
   "rotate":0,
   "sort_key":"new doc 4",
   "tag_ids":"",
   "doc_id":"ee4DM4Ly7CFBM3JFWAW60TUX",
   "co_token":"",
   "p":"XQXLDEQyA2hf6BBfyXhSaUHL",
   "t":"1474932063",
   "c":"2",
   "updated":"keyword1"
}
```

**Main**

```
var keyWordFilePath = @"keyWord.txt";
var jsonFilePath = @"json.txt";
var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFilePath);
var keywords = File.ReadAllText(keyWordFilePath).Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var key in keywords)
{

      //We are checking if json string contains key and also checking that it is only that definite key 
      var extractSpecificKey = jsonString.Substring(jsonString.IndexOf(key), key.Length+1);

      if (extractSpecificKey == key+ @"""")
      {

         Console.WriteLine($"Key {extractSpecificKey} present in json");

      }
     //False Positives
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine($"Key {key} NOT present in json");
      }
}

Console.Read();
```

**Output**

```
Key keyword NOT present in json
Key keyword1" present in json
```